# How to create a new line when condition match second time in sed or awk

Tags: awk, sed

I need to write a simply script to create a new line when second condition match in one line. The head is a fix condition but the text will be random in the file

Example data in a file:

```
head:texthead:text2
```

Expected result:

```
head:text
head:text2
```

Is any easy way to do this?

Comment: `sed 's/text/text\n/' file`

Comment: Hi @JamesBrown, the problem is that only head is fix but the text will be random

Comment: To avoid this being a QA session, please document all parameters to your question.

Comment: to insert newline before `head` when preceding is a letter, `sed -E 's/([a-z])(head)/\1\n\2/Ig' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace second occurrence of `head` with `<newline>head` using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/head/\nhead/2' file
head:text
head:text2
```

Comment: can also use `sed 's/head/\n\0/2'`